# Update records in database automatically

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let me describe my scenario here.

I am having a table with multiple records, where the name is the same, as it's gonna be records for the same person updated on daily basis.

Right now, I am trying to find out the easiest way to update all the names accordingly.

1. Name is going to be updated (TestName -> RealName)
2. I want this change to be applied to all the records with the same name, in this case, "TestName"

I can do a single query, but I am trying to find if there's an automatic way to do this correctly.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Been trying using a triggers, but in most cases, I am ending with an infinite loop, as I am trying to update the table, where a trigger is actually bound to, so it's invoking another update and so on.

I don't need an exact solution, just give me some ropes about how it can be achieved, please.

Comment: Not sure I get your problem correctly but this simple update should work: `update my_table set name = 'RealName' where name = 'TestName'`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but is there any way to do that automatically on SQL level? e.g triggers or some different mechanism?

Comment: The question is unclear, we do not know what you mean by *an automatic way*. If you want to do something automatically you have to define an event that triggers this update.

Comment: If you have a trigger causing an infinite loop, Show Us The Code! We're not mind readers, and your written description is very much unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be simply resolved by using the function [`pg_trigger_depth()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the trigger, e.g.:

```
create trigger before_update_on_my_table
before update on my_table
for each row 
when (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) -- this prevents recursion
execute procedure before_update_on_my_table();
```

However, it seems that the table is poorly designed. It should not contain names. Create a table with names (say `user_name`) and in the old table store a reference to the new one, e.g.:

```
create table user_name(id serial primary key, name text);

create table my_table(id serial primary key, user_id int references user_name(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event triggers in postgresql https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-createeventtrigger.html